# Distribution of squared multivariate normal random variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution, square-numbers

Let $W\sim MVN(\mu, \Sigma)$, here $W$ and $\mu$ are $k\times 1$ vector and $\Sigma$ is $k\times k$ symmetric matrix. And the diagonal elements of $\Sigma$ are equal to one.

For this multivariate random variable, I want to find 
$$P(max_{k=1,\ldots,K} W_k^2 >q_\alpha)$$
where $q_\alpha$ is the upper $\alpha$ quantile for the distribution of $max^2_{k=1,\ldots,K}$.

Chi-square distribution or wishart distribution is applicable in this case? 
Is there any way to derive the probability analytically or numerically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at https://mathematix.wordpress.com/2016/03/10/average-value-at-risk-of-simple-quadratic-form/ The chi-squared and the Wishart distribution are applicable depending on whether $\Sigma=I$ or $\Sigma$ is a general matrix and whether $\mu=0$. Derivations, nevertheless, can be cumbersome.